# Google Big Query : Window Function Row Wise Cumulative Sum Across Columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions, udf

I am looking to calculate cumulative sum across columns in Google Big Query.

Assume there are five columns `(NAME,A,B,C,D)` with two rows of integers, for example:

```
 NAME | A | B | C | D
----------------------
 Bob  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
 Carl | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8
```

I am looking for a windowing function or UDF to calculate the cumulative sum across rows to generate this output:

```
 NAME | A | B  | C  | D
-------------------------
 Bob  | 1 | 3  | 6  | 10
 Carl | 5 | 11 | 18 | 27
```

Any thoughts or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1):

I think, there are number of reasonable workarounds for your requirements mostly in the area of designing better your table. All really depends on how you input your data and most importantly how than you consume it

Still, if to stay with presented requirements - Below is not exactly what you expect in your question as an output, but might be usefull as an example:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(STRING(cum)) AS all FROM (
  SELECT name, 
    SUM(INTEGER(num)) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY name 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS cum
  FROM (
    SELECT name, SPLIT(all) AS num FROM (
      SELECT name, 
         CONCAT(STRING(a),',',STRING(b),',',STRING(c),',',STRING(d)) AS all 
      FROM yourtable
    )
  )
)
GROUP BY name
```

Output is:

```
name    all  
Bob     1,3,6,10     
Carl    5,11,18,26
```

Depends on how you than consume this data  - it still can work for you
Note, not you avoiding now writing something like col1 + col2 + .. + col89 + col90 - but still need to explicitelly mention each column just ones.

in case if you have "luxury" of implementing your requirements outside of GBQ UI, but rather in some [Client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries)- you can use [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/) to programatically aquire table schema and build on fly your logic/query and than execute it 
Take a look at below APIs to start with:
To get table schema  - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get
To issue query job - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a UDF:

```
SELECT name, a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d
FROM tab
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That definitely works with four columns, but would be problematic with say 90 columns

Comment: SQL needs be written or generated using some script, column names explicitly need be written in the query.

Comment: @echoecho256: When you got *90* columns you shouldn't write *4*. But anyway, *Windowing Functions* work on rows, not columns and a UDF would be called 90 times with different parameters or you need to create 90 different UDFs. Btw, looks like a denormalized table if you need to do a calculation like this...

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks again, I'll be sure to include more details next time regarding number of columns.